# How to get vote results from node reference through views?

Tags: nodes, views, rating

I have two content types:
1. Restaurant page
2. Write a review page
The write a review page has node reference url widget field and also the fivestar rating field. The image attached below will explain more:
[image]

I have created a view page, where I want to get vote average results for each restaurant (also if possible than on each individual restaurants page too). I basically want average result of ratings given to each restaurant page by the node reference content type which is write a review page.
Below are two images explaining my view:
[image]

And the preview:
[image]

Now I am really not sure what I am doing wrong here, I changed aggregation settings for all randomly to average to count to all the possible scenarios but nothing seems to work. The votingapi_vote table is also empty, I know that fivestar doesnt necessarily use those tables to store, but then how could I display the stars or even the average of all the ratings that restaurant has got?

------------ update 1 -------------------------

Here is the relationship content type which I am getting:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Can you add a relationship of referenced node? or referenced write a review?

If not use the [entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module instead. Add an entity reference field, with auto complete widget. Bundle type: Node.

Then in view add a relationship of referenced write a review.

Comment: I updated my answer, I have used the one which says in the end reverse, but it didnt help me. I am not actually aware of entity reference module, I felt its too much of learning for that.